# React Router - history being reverted after a render on a parent

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am storing some state in a context using `useState`, and using a `useEffect` in there to update history (via react-router-dom's `useHistory`).

After a user clicks a Cancel button, I clear these state values, and the `useEffect` then runs `history.replace({search: ""})`, emptying the query string.

However, if anything causes a re-render following that, the query string is restored with its previous value. This is despite the state in context being nulled out.

This happens without the `history.push` I use to update the query string in the first place, confirmed with debuggers, so it's happening somewhere outside of my code. It seems that, somehow, the **router is jumping back in history one step on the render following my emptying the query string**.

I'll try to write this in steps:

1. user interacts with a form
2. `useState` values in a context are bound to the inputs and update accordingly
3. `useEffect` watching those values uses `history.push` to update the query string (say `/home?field1=foo`)
4. user hits 'Cancel', which sets all of those state values to null
5. `useEffect` watching those values uses `history.replace` with `{search: ""}` (or `{}`), removing the query string from the URL (path is now `/home`)
6. user causes a re-render on an ancestor, and previous query string is restored to URL - `/home?field1=foo`

I'm at a loss, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't drilled down to the exact reason, but the problem here was that I was using `useLocation` and `useHistory` in multiple components, rendered at the same time. When `search` was updated, only the instance of `useHistory` that I called `push` or `replace` on would have the new state. The other instance would be left with the old state, and some other logic was causing it to use that false state to update the querystring again.

tl;dr if using `useLocation` and `useHistory` in multiple components, be careful as they are not aware of one another and not necessarily up to date as one would think.